# How to eliminate noise from Relay?

Tags: arduino, relay, noise, peltier

In my recent project, I am working with Peltier module. Now, here the main purpose of my project is switching between cooling and heating. And for that purpose, I'm using the 5V relay(2-relay) board. Now, during switching, the noise is generated from the relays and it totally destroys all functionality of the system.

First of all, let me explain the functionality of the system so you can understand the what is the role of the relay. In our system, we have to maintain the temperature at the desired time.

My system diagram looks like below:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Above is the most simple diagram. I just avoid the all actual connections and represent all connections in form of the bus. Now as you see in diagram different modules are there. Temperature sensor takes the reading which is attached with Peltier module. Now here motor driver is used for driving the Peltier module. LCD is used for display all data and keypad is used for entering the temperature and timer.

Now, here relays is used for the switching means for heating and cooling. By default, temperature is room temperature. Here we used 2-relay board in which one is used for cooling and other one used for heating.

For, switching for heating and cooling I just developed the logic like below.

```
if(desired_set_temp > peltier_temp)  // Heating
{
  relay 1 active
  relay 2 not active
}
if(desired_set_temp < peltier_temp)  // Cooling
{
  relay 1 not active
  relay 2 active
}
```

Now, the real problem starts here. Suppose, if we set temperature -5 degree then Peltier temperature try to maintain its temperature around -5 degree. and during this time switching happening and both relays generate noise. Now, how to eliminate this noise from these relays? Any circuit that removes this noise.

I used ready made relay board here like below:

[image: Relay]

***Edit**:* totally destroys all functionality of the system means during this time,

(1)LCD showing weird characters

(2)Can't able to operate the system

(3)Can't able to enter any value from Keypad

We have to compulsory restart the system and then we can able to operate system again.

Comment: "totally destroys all functionality of the system"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Dampmaskin Ok let me edit and clear that things.

Comment: I'm an amateur but would relays with (built in) optocouplers be a solution?

Comment: *"I just avoid the all actual connections"* Then we avoid providing any actual answers.  Most likely your grounding, bypassing, and/or power supply feed is badly done.  There is nothing more to say for such a vague question.

Comment: The switching from the reails you cannot overcome this way. What you need is a H-bridge Mosfet configuration to switch noiseless. How do you power your relais module? By the Arduino?

Comment: I expect you are powering the peltier modules from the same powersupply as the controller.  If the powersupply can't handle the load, the voltage to the controller would drop and cause the named problems.  But, who knows.  You haven't posted a schematic.

Comment: @Hans: That was my first guess too, but he's apparently using a relay module.  Presumably the module was designed by someone that can actually spell EE.

Comment: Disconnect the peltier modules and see if it still misbehaves when the relays switch.

Comment: Either EMI or power supply droop is disrupting your micro. You have not supplied enough information to figure out what you are doing wrong. Please do so.

Comment: If your trying to drive the peliter directly from your audino GPIO as stated in the diagram, your going to have all sorts of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Add hysteresis:

```
auto active_error = 5;//or whatever
auto passive_error = 2;//or whatever
if(desired_set_temp > peltier_temp + allowed_error)  // Heating
{
  relay 1 active
  relay 2 not active
}
if(desired_set_temp < peltier_temp - allowed_error)  // Cooling
{
  relay 1 not active
  relay 2 active
}

if(desired_set_temp >= peltier_temp - passive_error &&
   desired_set_temp <= peltier_temp + passive_error)  // goldilocks zone
{
  relay 1 not active
  relay 2 not active
}
```

This will add a delay between switching one and the other.

In this case it will activate the heater or cooler when the temperature exceeds the set temp `+/-active_error` and deactivate when it come back within `+/-passive_error`.